# Using char in struct

Tags: c, list, static, struct, char

I need to make a c program to represent a list with students data (name, score and student number) but I can't figure out how to correctly store the students names.

I tried to use pointer but when I try to assign a new name, it overwrites the old one.

Here is the code I'm using...can anyone help me?

**lista.h**

```
typedef struct _lista lista;
typedef struct _dados dados;

typedef struct _dados{
    int matricula;
    float media;
    char *nome;
}_dados;

typedef struct _lista {
    int fim;
    dados *d[max];
}_lista;

lista* criar_lista();
dados* novo_dado(char *nome, int matricula, float media);
void imprimir(dados *dado);
```

**lista.c**

```
lista* criar_lista(){
    lista* L = (lista *) malloc(sizeof (lista));
    L->fim = -1;
    return L;
}

dados* novo_dado(char *nome, int matricula, float media){

    dados* d = (dados *) malloc(sizeof (dados));
    d -> matricula = matricula;
    d -> media = media;
    d -> nome = nome;
    return d;
}

void imprimir(dados *dado){
    printf("%s: ", dado->nome);
    printf("%d ", dado->matricula);
    printf("%.2f\n", dado->media);
}
```

**main.c**

```
lista *L1;
char nome[15];
int matricula;
float media;

L1 = criar_lista();



for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    fscanf(entrada,"%s", nome);
    fscanf(entrada,"%d", &matricula);
    fscanf(entrada,"%f", &media);
    inserir(L1,novo_dado(nome,matricula,media));

}
```

input:

```
8
Vandre 45 7.5
Joao 32 6.8
Mariana 4 9.5
Carla 7 3.5
Jose 15 8
Fernando 18 5.5
Marcos 22 9
Felicia 1 8.5
```

output:

```
Felicia 45 7.5
Felicia 32 6.8
Felicia 4 9.5
Felicia 7 3.5
Felicia 15 8
Felicia 18 5.5
Felicia 22 9
Felicia 1 8.5 and so on...
```

Comment: "when I try to assign a new name, it overwrites the old one." — That's how assignment normally works. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You keep using the same `char nome[15]` over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
d -> nome = nome;
```

to

```
d -> nome = strdup(nome);
```

This will allocate a new char array on the heap, copy the string to it, and set `d->nome` to the start of it. Thus each `dado` will have its own `nome` string in its own array.

Just before you destroy a `dado`, don't forget to call `free(d->nome);`, otherwise you have a memory leak.